# How to use ListSelectionListener in 3 table with database

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I wanna ask problem about list selection listener. In my application, I have 3 Jtable, lets say the first table is Student table, filled by student information, the second is semester table, filled by some semesters to the correspondent student (semester 1 to x), and the last table is result table, filled by result on the correspondent semester.

What i want to do is when I click a row in student table, semester table will update it's data, for example, it will filled by semester 1 to 6. Then, when i click a row in semester table, the result table will update it's data.

I can do it from student table to semester table with listselectionlistener and overriding valueChanged method. But how should i do for the same for semester table to result table? I'm getting stuck on this...

- i use database to retrieve all values to jtable -

edited : now I used SwingWorker, but i have another problem :

1. When the UI is showing, the master table display a row (this is true)
2. When i try to clicked that row, it dont clicked, i mean usually u will get a background in a selected row, but not with me (wrong->my problem)
3. It also throw NullPointerException at my child table
4. But when i wait for a while, it suddenly work again...

i've uploaded my sample code, and remove unrelated code here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67181952/mycode.java

2nd code for error in child table
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67181952/spk.java

I hope i explained well, sorry for my bad english.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListSelectionListener` added to selection models that you can get with [getSelectionModel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectionModel%28%29).

Maintain the logic of presentation using table models. Once selection in `master` table changes update model/models of `details` tables accordingly. As a result of the data update, the model will notify its view (the table) about the changes. And view will refresh accordingly.

Read more about models in [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

**EDIT:**

Since you load the data from database be sure to do it *not from* Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) to avoid performance issues. Look into [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform lengthy operations on a dedicated thread. Read more about [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

**EDIT: following code upload**

It seems that you misinterpreting `SwingWorker` specs. `execute()` method is not blocking, it schedules worker execution and returns immediately. UI updates should be done in `process()` or `done()` methods, which are invoked by the worker on EDT. Below is a revised version of one of the of functions from the code you posted:

```
public void retrieveDetailTransaction(final String noTrans){
    SwingWorker<List<TransactionDetail>, Void> worker = 
      new SwingWorker<List<TransactionDetail>, Void>() {

      public List<TransactionDetail> doInBackground() {
        List<TransactionDetail> listTransD = transDetailControl.select(noTrans);
        return listTransD;
      }

      public void done() {
        try {
           listTransDetail = get();

           transDetailModel.setListTransaction(listTransDetail);
           transactionDetailTable.setModel(transDetailModel);       

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   };
   worker.execute();       
}
```

Comment: i finally can make it with selectionlistener as you mention above, but my app get freeze, not responding when i clicked for the 4/5th time. What's wrong? this is my overrided valueChanged

if (transactionTable.getSelectionModel()==e.getSource())
                {
                    //some code
                }
                else if (transactionDetailTable.getSelectionModel()==e.getSource()){
                    //some code
                }

Comment: @mKorbel filtering is a great and simple solution if you have all data at hand.

Comment: @mKorbel yes, i load it from database

Comment: right that I understood from original question, but OP's comment in your answer talking about EDT issue

Comment: @bangandi then edit your question with this very important info :-)

Comment: @Max you mention about filtering, i know how to use it, so i load all data first, and keep using ListSelectionListener, when valueChanged, i filter the data, is that do you mean?

Comment: @bangandi how many row are in the Database, altogether for all three JTables, this could be most important info, about corrct suggestion(s) which of way is better for that

Comment: @bangandi filtering was an answer to my comment(that I sent to Max), leave that in this moment

Comment: @mKorbel for now, for all, it's just 5 row, just for example, but it can be hundreds of row,maybe thousands, because i build a transaction app for a shop..

Comment: @bangandi you should not access database from EDT, see my edit about SwingWorker.

Comment: @Max now i used swingworker but at first when i try to click in a row in my master table, it returns an exception, and i can't clicked on the row (the selected background not displayed), but after some click and click, i get the feature again, and the child table get the updates. What's wrong with my logic? I use swing worker when in my retrieve method, and the retrieve method i call inside ValueChanged method

Comment: @bangandi it is hard to guess without looking at the code. Try to compose a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates the issues. Update your question with this code.

Comment: @Max great. My problem solved big thanks for you. This is my first time i used SwingWorker, so i still have lots of missunderstanding. but one last problem, for example there is 2 row in TransactionDetail table. When i click on first row, which is have child, the spkTable updated. When i click the second row, which is doesnt have child, the child table showing empty row. This is true, until when i perform some click again and again, the spkTable keeps empty...

Comment: @Max please see my code in my question, sorry for bothering you

Comment: @bangandi The implementation of the `SPKTableModel` is not visible, so it hard to say for certain. But for sure, do not call `fireTableRowsDeleted` and `fireTableDataChanged` explicitly. The model itself will execute these methods as result of data modification to notify the table.

Comment: @Max as you mentioned above, i move those methods to spktablemodel, but it seems not fixing the problem. The implementation of SPKTableModel is in here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67181952/spktablemodel.java

Comment: @bangandi Looks like you can simply call `setListSPK(listSPK)` with empty list to clear the table. Also, don't execute `spkTable.setModel(spkTableModel);` within SwingWorker. Do it before - when you allocate the table and the model. Then in SwingWorker simply update the model. Moreover, in your code you call `setModel` based on `if` condition which may never happen.

Comment: @Max "Then in SwingWorker simply update the model". Do you mean i simply call setListSPK(listSPK)? If yes, i've done exactly like you said, also i add fireTableDataChanged() in setListSPK method, but the previous error still happened. I'm still workin out with this problem. It's confusing error, no message, nothing at all...

Comment: @bangandi I'm not sure I uderstand what is the problem you describing. Try to debug `retrieveSPK` and make sure you do read valid data, and that `fireTableDataChanged` is actually executed.

Comment: okay, i will do that later, i have another job to do today, I think it's enough for me now. You really help me @max, thank you so much!

Comment: @max sorry bother you again, i do as you mentioned before, i debug so many times in different place, and i found that at some point, my spkdao(for accessing data) is not touched, i mean my app doesn't reach the line for accessing data. Is that means the event didn't detected?

Comment: i found something, my app has view, model, and control. The error is when reaching line that calling the controller, so the event is detected, but somehow the controller suddenly not working, all of that...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I use a MouseListener (mouseClick event) to work with JTables. First, when you click in the first table, you save the object that represent a student in that line and tells the second table do update. The same thing will be done to the second. For each click, you save the semester object and updates the third table. Off course, you can do the same thing using the ListSelectionListener. I think you are already doing this, but you need two different event listeners. One for the first and another for the second table.